# TeamCity artifacts containing 0b files

Tags: artifacts, teamcity-7.0

We are using TeamCity 7.1.2, and have encountered a problem with the artifacts generated by our continuous build.

Specifically, when we have moved files around in the source that is used for our artifacts, TeamCity is creating zero byte size versions of these files in their previous locations (as well as correct copies in their new locations).

You can easily see this in TeamCity.

[image: TeamCity 0b files]

The various 0b files shown in the `InstallScripts` folder *used* to be in this folder, but have since been moved to the `Modules` and `Scripts` folders.

Has anyone else seen this, and if so were you able to fix this issue? We have already done an *Enforce clean checkout* in TeamCity, but this did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Have you updated the "Artifact paths" in the "General Settings" page of your build Configuration?

Comment: @JifengZhang - yes, we certainly have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to be a [known issue that is fixed in Perforce 7.1.3](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-24046).

For now, we are using the workaround of switching our build configurations to use [agent-side checkout rather than server-side checkout](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5251095).